# How do I check if the 3ds charger is plugged in?

Tags: c++, nintendo-3ds

I am writting a function to know wether or not the charger is plugged in my 3ds however my function keep returning false while the charger is plugged in.

I expect my function to return true if the charger is plugged in my 3ds.

Here is the function:

```cpp
bool isChargerPluggedin() {
    bool chargeState;
    PTMU_GetAdapterState(&chargeState);
    return chargeState == 1;
}
```

My first attempt to solve my problem was to allocate memory to the chargeState  variable:

```cpp
bool isChargerPluggedin() {
    bool *chargeState = new bool;
    PTMU_GetAdapterState(chargeState);
    bool state = *chargeState == 1;
    delete chargeState;
    return state;
}
```

My second attempt was by using an global variable to chargeState instead of a local variable :

```cpp
bool chargeState;
bool isChargerPluggedin() {
    PTMU_GetAdapterState(&chargeState);
    return chargeState == 1;
}
```

Comment: `return chargeState == 1;` --> `return chargeState;` -- There is no need for `==1`.  Second, maybe the issue is with `PTMU_GetAdapterState`, and not this code.  Also, the first code is the one that should have worked.  The second attempt using `new` and `delete` are not necessary, and just needlessly calls the allocator, slowing the code down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you must initialize first the libraries in your main function using the function `ptmuInit`. You must deinitialize the library before your program exitHere is a example:

```c
int main() {
  ptmuInit();
  // program loop
  while (true) {
    bool isPlugged = isChargerPluggedin();
    ...
  }
  ptmuExit();
}
```